# Maximum Likelihood Estimator of rate parameter of the exponential distribution (MLE)

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, optimization, inference

I want to find the maximum likelihood estimator of the "rate parameter theta of the Exponential Distribution".

So i followed the following commands in `R`:

```
 x=rexp(500,rate=2)
 f <- function(x,theta){
        sum(-dexp(x,rate=theta,log=T))
 }
 optimize(f=f,x=x,interval=c(0,5))
```

#### I do not understand the logic - *why do we consider `maximum=FALSE(default)` in the `optimize` function?*

#### Why haven't we used `maximum=TRUE` to find the MLE?

Comment: I must be missing your point, but the maximum likelihood estimator of the rate parameter of an exponential is the reciprocal of the mean. Invoking an optimizer should get you the right answer but is like going from Paris to Versailles via Vladivostok.

Comment: @NickCox Would you please tell me the proper way to find MLE?

Comment: Maximize the likelihood, naturally. Not trying to outsmart you, but what answer are you seeking? The particular method depends on whether there is a closed form solution that gets you there in one (unusual, but true in this case) or you have to estimate it numerically.

Comment: I agree with @NickCox - the only purpose I can see to this exercise would be if it were part of an introduction to finding MLEs numerically by beginning with an example you can also easily do by hand. Which implies you're doing this for some subject. Is that the case?

Comment: @Glen_b yes. I want to find MLE by using `R`. It is one of my course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term inside your definition of `f` :- `sum(-dexp(x,rate=theta,log=T))` is NOT the likelihood, but something else.

What is it that is being calculated?

When you consider what it is that is being optimized there, you will also understand why you're minimizing that function in order to maximize the likelihood.

To quote your own algebra, here's the likelihood:

$\cal{L}(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\theta e^{-\theta x_i}=\theta^n e^{-\theta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$

`dexp` with `log=TRUE` doesn't return the density. Here's what the help says: `log, log.p   logical; if TRUE, probabilities p are given as log(p).` ... that is when you say `log=TRUE` you get the log of the density.

The likelihood at $\theta$ will be the product of the densities, taken at each data point.

The log-likelihood is the sum of the log-densities, over the data points, evaluated at a given $\theta$.

That is, `sum(dexp(x,rate=theta,log=T))` would be the *log-likelihood function*. We'd want to maximize that.

But we have `sum(-dexp(x,rate=theta,log=T))`  (don't ask me why they didn't write the obviously equivalent but presumably faster `-sum(dexp(x,rate=theta,log=T))`).

That is, the program is minimizing the negative log-likelihood, which is equivalent to maximizing the log-likelihood. Here's the result on calling `f` on theta values between 1 and 3:

[image]

By contrast, this is what the likelihood function looks like:

[image]

> `sum(dexp(x,rate=theta,log=T))` is calculating $θ^ne^{−θ∑^n_{i=1}x_i}$?

It's calculating the log of that quantity.

> But here I see I have the minus sign in every program related to MLE in my lecture sheet.

Minimizing rather than maximizing is a convention. There's no particular need for it.

> The R documentation is saying that in `optim` function `par Initial values for the parameters to be optimized over`. How can I select the initial values?
>
> Would you please tell me how can I relate this program
>   `fexp = function(theta, x){ prod(dexp(x,rate=(1/theta))) }`
>   `res3<-optimize(f=fexp,interval=c(0,50), maximum=T, x=x)`
>   `res3`
>
> with my above program that I have posted in the question?
>
> Why here is the `prod` function being called?

Because the likelihood is a product.

> And why here we have mentioned maximum=T?

Because it's computing the likelihood, which we want to maximize.

Edit: I notice another issue with the above code: it says `rate = 1/theta`. That implies
that the `theta` there is not the rate parameter of your earlier mathematics and code, but is in fact a *scale parameter*. Watch out for that! Another thing to watch out for is that likelihood calculations often have underflow problems (and sometimes, overflow problems).

Comment: Actually i have missed the class for political unrest in our country. So it would be very kind if you explain me what the above commands are trying to proof ?

Comment: This comment: "i have missed the class for political unrest in our country" is such a *non sequitur* as to require explanation. Are you actually saying that you're learning **to compute MLEs in R** during a class on political unrest?  If you don't understand what your code is doing, it's hardly surprising that it makes no sense to you. Do you know what the likelihood function for the exponential rate parameter is? Could you write it down?

Comment: @Glen_b My second reading was that Harry missed a class **because of** political unrest in his country.

Comment: @NickCox ah, that makes more sense. OP, my question on the exponential likelihood stands. Do you know  what the likelihood function for the exponential rate parameter is? Could you write it down? (If you can, please do so, preferably in your question). If you can't, *that* is probably closer to where your actual question lies.

Comment: The likelihood function is $L=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\theta e^{-\theta x_i}=\theta^n e^{-\theta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$ . And the MLE can be found by taking log of the likelihood function and then differentiating the log likelihood function with respect to $\theta $ and set it to zero which yields $\hat\theta=\frac{1}{\bar x} $. I have learnt the process in our inference class. But now i have to compute it in `R`.

Comment: Okay, thanks harry. Knowing more about what you know leaves me in a better place to answer your question. Can you see what is calculated in `f`?

Comment: No , i am not understanding the command `sum(-dexp(x,rate=theta,log=T))` and also the reason of minimizing the function.

Comment: See the new last part of my answer - what does `dexp` return when `log=TRUE`? (If you're not sure, take a look at `?dexp`)

Comment: `dexp(x,rate=theta,log=T)` -this is computing the density function of exponential variate x with 50 valuse and the `sum` command is computing the sum of these 50 probabilities. But what is the function of this minus(-)sign inside it?

Comment: `dexp` with `log=TRUE` doesn't return the density. Here's what the help says: `log, log.p  logical; if TRUE, probabilities p are given as log(p).` ... that is when you say `log=TRUE` you get the log of the density.

Comment: And with log is that x's are given as log(x)?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question there. Take another look at my updated answer. I will say your replies come so quickly that it suggests you're not spending enough time *thinking* about the replies you are getting. Stop. Slow down. Investigate. Contemplate.

Comment: Is the purpose of MLE to minimize the function for every probability density ? or sometimes we have to maximize the function to get MLE? Is that taking differentiation with respect to the parameter and set it to zero is the process of minimization? I knew it as the process of maximization.

Comment: What happens if you calculate directly $\theta exp(-\theta x)$ for a particular $x$ and $\theta$. How does it compare with `dexp(x,theta)`? How does it compare with `dexp(x,theta,log=TRUE)`? How does that compare with `log(dexp(x,theta))`?

Comment: The first two will yield the same result that is our density and The last two will yield the same result that is the log of our density .

Comment: Right. So what would `sum(dexp(x,theta,log=TRUE))` be in terms of the problem you want to solve? (note: my code there doesn't have the minus. We'll get to that.)

Comment: $sum(dexp(x,rate=theta,log=T)) $ is calculating $ \theta^n e^{-\theta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$? But here i see i have the minus sign in every program related to MLE in my lecture sheet.

Comment: The R documentation is saying that in `optim` function `par  

Initial values for the parameters to be optimized over.` How can i select the initial values?

Comment: I have found my answer.Many thanks to you. Would you please tell me how can i relate this program  `fexp = function(theta, x){
prod(dexp(x,rate=(1/theta)))
}
res3<-optimize(f=fexp,interval=c(0,50), maximum=T, x=x);
res3
` with my above program that i have posted in the question?Why here the `prod` function is being called?And why here we have mentioned `maximum=T`?Is that because of we didn't call a minus sign here?

Comment: Oh, it's now clear . `prod(dexp(x,rate=theta))` is calculating $\prod_{i=1}^{n}\theta e^{-\theta x_i}$ . You are really a nice teacher , also a wise person i have ever seen before. Thank you very very very much.

Comment: You have it. I have also added a little on it in my answer; it's a bit slower getting your answers this way, but you'll remember it better.